# how to programmatically set a value of Treelist in sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6

I have a job description page, and I am adding values to it programmatically. One of the fields is "Office Locations", with a data type of Treelist. How can I add values to the Treelist so that I can set the office location?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Sitecore** `Treelist` stores the ids of selected items in a pipeline separated form.

If you want to set the value of `Treelist` programmatically you need to set it to a string which looks like:

```
{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}|{EA015A5F-C41B-4510-B538-438EF204F5E2}
```

where `{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}`, `{EA015A5F-C41B-4510-B538-438EF204F5E2}` and possibly more of the string parts separated with `|` characters are ids of chosen pages.

```c#
using (new EditContext(jobItem))
{
    jobItem["OfficeLocations"] = "{110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}|{EA015A5F-C41B-4510-B538-438EF204F5E2}";
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Maras  . i set the value using below can you confirm this is recommemded way.

Comment: Items[] US = masterDb.SelectItems("/sitecore/content/home/united  states/*[@@templatename='test']");     Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multiselectField =  newItem.Fields["OfficeLocations"];
                        foreach(Item state in USstates)
                        {
                            if (state.Name.ToLower() == _stateName)
                            {
                                multiselectField.Value =state.ID.ToString();
                            }
                        }

Comment: Yes, your code should work just fine assuming that there is only one state with its name equal to `_stateName`. But you need to use EditContext as in my answer or newItem.BeginEdit() and .EndEdit()

Comment: _statename is based on the job location and i am using EditContext . the code i showed is just for treelist office location field.

Comment: Instead of manually building the value, you can use ListString class. See example here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551900/sitecore-set-multi-reference-field-value-programatically/26551901#26551901