# Sitecore set multi reference field value programmatically

Tags: sitecore

How to set a multi-reference field value programmatically if I have collection of items/ids?

E.g. Build following raw value "{guid1}|{guid2}|{guid3}..."

---

In my specific case I need to import a tree of items and on one level a parent was using children as repository and it also had a multi reference list to a subset of the children based on some criteria. I wanted to build a flexible list based on ordering or filtering and then set value of parent without making code specific to a list type - parent field can be any list.

E.g. Custom list with rule "where [is odd] orderby child desc" build for each Parent and set to field "Odd"

- Parent1 -> Parent1["Odd"] = 5

  - 2
  - 5
- Parent2 -> Parent2["Odd"] = 3,1

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to programmatically set a value of Treelist in sitecore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233509/how-to-programmatically-set-a-value-of-treelist-in-sitecore)

Comment: "... Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions ... "
http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel Both my question and answer are MUCH more generic (better) than the possible duplicate that you have referenced

Comment: Yup, Jeff Attwood even blogged about it: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/ Don't like the question/answer? Then downvote it.

Comment: Fair enough - I will correct it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use class `Sitecore.Text.ListString` to build the value

Example:

```
// Incomplete code snippet assumes variable Item item with list field "References" 
// and IEnumerable<ID> references

Sitecore.Text.ListString referencesValue = new Sitecore.Text.ListString();

foreach(ID id in references)
{
   string idString = id.ToString();
   if (!referencesValue.Contains(idString))
   {
       referencesValue.Add(idString);
   }
}    

item.Editing.BeginEdit();
item["References"] = referencesValue.ToString();
item.Editing.EndEdit();
```

Comment: I'm confused, you asked this question 15 minutes ago, and then answered it yourself less than a minute later...are you just looking for votes, or...?

Comment: This is also not the best way to do this. Reference the [Sitecore Content API Cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/64/content_api_cookbook_sc64_and_later-usletter.pdf)

Comment: @ZacharyKniebel Stackoverflow allows (even encourages) posting a question and answer immediately after, as long as the question has not been asked. I just shared my research since I could not easily find an answer on the web for the problem at hand.

The problem that I had was that I needed a generic solution to set multi reference value without specifying an explicit type for the field.

Comment: Fair enough. Out of curiosity, may I ask why you could not specify the explicit type for the field? (Also, if you could add that factor of the scenario to your question, that would be great)

Comment: The field type is intentionally not specified so that solution is generic and works with different types - Multilist, Treelist, or any custom type as long as the format of the raw value remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

According to the cookbook link provided by Zachary, this seems to be the correct way to access such a field:

```
    Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField multiselectField = item.Fields["multiselect"]
```

> The individual members of the list returned by
>   `Sitecore.Data.Fields.MultilistField.GetItems()` method are never Null. If a user has deleted an item without updating the references to that item, the
>   `GetItems()` method excludes that item from its results. [...] You can add items to a supported field type using the
>   `Sitecore.Data.Fields.MulitlistField.Add()` method, and remove items using the
>   `Sitecore.Data.Fields.MulitlistField.Remove()` method.

Comment: Indeed so. The marked answer is considered bad practice.